# SchemaToolTask not found in datanucleus-rdbms.jar

Tags: rdbms, datanucleus

I have started with data nucleus a couple of days ago.

I have downloaded the jdo tutorial and am trying to run it.

I have collected all the jar files related to the tutorial [here](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_1_0/guides/jdo/tutorial.html) .

I am using ant for building. "compile" and "enhance" tasks work fine. The "createschema" task is spitting the following error out!

> ```
> C:\datanucleus\datanucleus-samples-jdo-tutorial-3.0\build.xml:123:
> ```
>
> taskdef clas
>       org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.SchemaToolTask
>   cannot be found

I have checked datanucleus-rdbms.jar for the SchemaToolTask and I didn't find that class in the jar file.

I downloaded it from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/datanucleus/files/datanucleus-rdbms/3.0.0.m3/) .

Why is that class not there?? Am I using the wrong jar file?

Comment: The runtutorial task runs without running the createschema task. So, I ignored this for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that I was using source jar files instead of the binaries.

[Closing the question by marking this as the answer]

Answer (score 2):

Why would you download 3.0 and use it with a tutorial for v 1.0?

Comment: Good question. I didn't even notice that!!

However, is there a tutorial for 3.0?? Seems like you are the best person to answer why the website is still holding these links??

Thank You

Comment: Actually, the text I'm reading is of 1.0, but, the demo/files I downloaded are 3.0. I picked up the ant tasks from the read me and it failed with the above error.

It shouldn't fail in that case, right???

Answer (score 0):

In version 3.x the location of the SchemaToolTask changed from:

org.datanucleus.store.rdbms

to:

org.datanucleus.store.schema

reflecting the fact that the Schema tool is datastore agnostic.

Comment: I found the problem long back. Only I didn't update it here. For few jars, I have downloaded source files instead of binaries. Downloading a lot of jars is such a pain!!